# sshfs permenant mounting without password prompt

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, sshfs

I have two Linux machines

```
Linux 1
Linux 2
```

I mount a directory on Linux2 to Linux one as below:

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other MYUSER@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/usr/XXXXX/bin /opt/Project/MountHere/
```

This works, but it's not permanent and each time I run it it asks for password.

what I need to do, to create a permanent mount without asking for password.

how can I do that?

I tries the following in

> /etc/fstab

but after restart still the mounted directory is empty

```
sshfs#MYUSER@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/usr/XXXXX/bin /opt/Project/MountHere/ fuse.sshfs defaults 0 0
```

Comment: `sshfs` uses SSH as transport. If you manage to make `ssh MYUSER@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX` work without password, `sshfs` will also work this way.

Comment: use ssh keys. Always use ssh keys instead of password. https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/key

Answer (score 0):

archlinux has a nice howto: [SSHFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSHFS).  You need to make sure root can connect to the other system without password (ie. using keys and an IdentityFile).